# If a group 's socle is $Sz(q)$, how can I determine its maximal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, socle

As the title says,I want to know the maximal subgroup of the group whose socle is $Sz(q)$.
If there are such papers,could you tell its name or give me a link.
Thank a lot

Comment: Is this really homework? A maximal subgroup of such a group is the normalizer of a maximal subgroup of ${\rm Sz}(q)$, and these are classified in the original paper by Suzuki, but this is a nontrivial result, and the proof involves a lot of case-by-case analysis.

Comment: Oh,my teacher wants me to study the subgroup form of such group,how can I find the paper .If it's allowed ,could you give me the detail information,such as the name of paper that contain trivial result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suzuki's original paper on the Suzuki groups is:

M. Suzuki. On a class of doubly transitive groups. Ann. of Math. (2) 75 (1962),
105–145.

He classifies the maximal subgroup of the groups themselves, but not of their almost simple extensions.

It turns out that there are o novelty subgroups in the almost simple extensions, so their maximals are just the normalizers of the maximals of the Suzuki group together with those containing the socle. This is proved in Chapter 7 of the recently published book:

The Maximal Subgroups of the Low-Dimensional Finite Classical Groups
J.N. Bray, D.F. Holt, C.M. Roney-Dougal,
London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series 407, CUP, 2013.

http://www.cambridge.org/co/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/maximal-subgroups-low-dimensional-finite-classical-groups